# How do I delete a workspace using tf.exe that starts with a dash/hyphen?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tf-cli, tfvc

I have a specific command that I use to delete a Team Foundation Server workspace:

```
tf workspace /delete "packages sacred";domain\user /server:http://domain:8080/tfs
```

We've recently had someone leave who prefixed about half of his workspaces with a dash/hyphen, so running my usual command line

`tf workspace /delete "-name";domain\user /server:http://domain:8080/tfs`

returns the error `Unrecognized command option 'name;domain\user'.`

If I try using `"^-name"` I get `TF14061: The workspace ^-name;FirstName LastName does not exist.`

`tf workspace /delete ^-name;domain\user /server:http://domain:8080/tfs`

returns the error `Unrecognized command option 'name;domain\user'.` as well.

Double hyphen and single quotes doesn't work either.

Ideally I'd like to know how to delete a workspace that starts with a hyphen using the `tf` command line tool, so unless it's impossible, I'm not looking for a link to another tool to use. Is there a way to escape the name correctly?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in the `tf` client and I do not see (while browsing the decompiled code of tf.exe) any attempt to escape a `/` or `-` at the start of any argument. If you have access to the workspace itself, on the client machine, you can use `tf workspace /newname:ANewName` to change it, but any 'free' argument that starts with a `-` will cause issues.

You'll probably need a tool like the [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) (workspace sidekick should do) or script the deletion of the workspace through the TFS Client Object Model and Powershell.